# how to handle cloudinary error in strapi application and prevent the strapi dashboard from crashing?

Tags: error-handling, strapi, cloudinary

I have a Strapi application where i use Cloudinary as my provider for file upload, so far everything has been working great.

but it seems like there is a limit to the upload size of the file, the file should not exceed 10MB. this is OK and it is Cloudinaries policy. the problem is every time in my Strapi Admin dashboard a user tries to upload a file more than 10MB it throws an error and the whole server stops with this message:

```
/Users/m-store/Ovanya/grie-production/node_modules/@strapi/provider-upload-cloudinary/dist/index.js:57
                            reject(new utils.errors.PayloadTooLargeError());
                               ^

PayloadTooLargeError: Entity too large
    at /Users/m-store/Ovanya/grie-production/node_modules/@strapi/provider-upload-cloudinary/dist/index.js:57:36
    at /Users/m-store/Ovanya/grie-production/node_modules/cloudinary/lib/utils/index.js:1354:14
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/m-store/Ovanya/grie-production/node_modules/cloudinary/lib/uploader.js:510:9)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1358:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  details: {}
}
✨  Done in 71.43s.
```

here is an image of the visual error after uploading a large file of more than 10MB, after this error, the Strapi dashboard crashes.

[image]

how can I prevent this error from stopping the Strapi process completely?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can find solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64136483/cloudinary-file-too-large